# Overridding Bootstrap in Joomla

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla3.0, overriding

I am trying to change certain parts of my custom made template on Joomla. For example I have a h1 in the header and I wish to change its color and font. Using Chromes inspect element I have determined that the part I need to change is in the bootstrap.min.css file but I don't have this in my template and do not wish to edit the file that is accessible and updateable by Joomla. I have given the h1 an id and tried to reference it through my custom.css file but it continues to be overridden by the bootstrap file. How can I make my site completely changeable through my own custom css avoiding bootstraps overriding.

Comment: Can you see your h1 ID being overwritten by the Joomla CSS in inspector, if yes then try to call your custom CSS after Joomla has called the default CSS.

Comment: Yes I believe I have, the last link in my head tag is <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">. When I change the h1 from bootstrap.min.css in the inspector it changes, copying the same code into my custom.css is not making any change

Comment: can you physically change the line h1 in the min.css file and save it compile / run the code and see if it persist.. ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Joomla 3.0 then this tutorial explains the best way to add custom CSS file [Custom CSS in Joomla](https://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/customization/the-best-way-to-add-custom-css-styles-to-joomla-3-template)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my custom css was not working. In Joomla you have to be more specific as to where the file is located **../css/custom.css** will not do. Instead **templates/nameoftemplate/css/custom.css**